# Why are the efficiencies of real heat pumps so far from the theoretical limits?

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-engine, efficient-energy-use

The theoretical coefficient of performance of a heat pump for warming is $\frac{T_h}{\Delta T}$.  Take an example of an outdoor temperature of -15C and an indoor of 20C, one then has COP = 293/35 = 8.37.  Next, look at all actual heat pumps (for example the list at https://www.ahridirectory.org/) and one finds that at -15C (5F) the highest COP is 2.2. That is not even close.  There have been DOE competitions to create better cold-weather heat pumps, but they hit the same limit. Instead, the responses have improved the output Btu/hrs, not the efficiency.  What physical effects result in this whopping failure to reach even close to the theoretical limit?

PS -  A few days after posting, it occurred to me that the most important factor could be that home use heat pumps do not recover work of expansion.  The vapor just expands freely out a small hole.  Total W is substantially larger than the theoretical value if W expansion is not subtracted.  Is this the key issue?

Comment: But I did not ask for an engineering solution.  I asked for the physical principles that make the COP lower than the theoretical limit.  The answer, apparently, is found in the American Journal of Physics.  Engineers may not read that generally.

Comment: The engineering answer is that nothing reaches the theoretical limit since reality intrudes.

Comment: I think it is a relevant question for this site as it is asking for the  apparent inability of present technology to reach a *theoretical* optimum and @MichaelSeifert has given the underlying reason. Maybe the question could be rephrased as to why heat pumps seem to be less efficient than, say, electric refrigerators.

Answer (score 9):

Heat pumps can't operate at the thermodynamic efficiency limit because you don't want them to take an infinite amount of time to transfer heat into your house.

Think about a heat engine first.  A Carnot engine operating "at" thermodynamic efficiency between two reservoirs takes an infinitely long time to complete one cycle. This is because in the idealized Carnot cycle, the working fluid is at the temperature of the hot reservoir when it accepts heat;  it has to be, or it will generate entropy as the heat flows.  Similarly, the working fluid must be at the temperature of the "cold" reservoir when it rejects its heat.

In practical terms, what this means is that the closer an engine is to Carnot efficiency, the slower its operation will be.  Remember that the *rate* of heat flow between two objects is proportional to $\Delta T$;  which then means that the time for the working fluid to gain or reject a particular amount of energy is *inversely* proportional to the $\Delta T$ between the working fluid and the reservoirs.  If the working fluid is 0.1°C cooler than the hot reservoir when it gains its heat, the heat flow will be relatively slow;  if the working fluid is 10°C cooler, then it will absorb a given amount of heat faster but it will also be correspondingly less efficient because it is generating more entropy. It is an interesting exercise to use these two facts to maximize the *power output* of a Carnot engine; it can be shown<sup>1</sup> that at maximum power output for a given set of reservoirs, we have
$$
e = 1 - \sqrt{\frac{T_c}{T_h}}
$$
which, as it turns out, is a much better estimate of the efficiency of "real" heat engines.

While the above is all about engines, heat pumps operate under the same sort of operational constraints.  They can't operate arbitrarily slowly, because the house is continually losing heat via the walls & windows, and the heat pump has to keep up with that in order to keep the house comfortable.  That means that the heat pump can't operate at the thermodynamic efficiency limit.  What's more, the heat pump has to provide heat to the house at a *greater* rate when the temperature is colder, since the conduction to the outside will be greater in such conditions.  That means that it will necessarily be operating further from the thermodynamic efficiency limit precisely when the efficiency limit is lower.

---

<sup>1</sup> F. L. Curzon & B. Ahlborn, "Efficiency of a Carnot engine at maximum power output", *Am. J. Phys.* **41**, 22–24 (1975).  Also, D. V. Schroeder's *An Introduction to Thermal Physics* poses a simplified version of this question as Problem 4.6.

Comment: Penfield: Available power from a nonideal thermal source, J. Appl. Phys. 32, 1793–1794 (1961)https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1728450

Comment: Usually, the COP of heat pump is the inverse of the heat engine.  One is Q/W, the other is W/Q.  But, then I get a COP of 16 when at optimal power point and  my example of Tc =-15 C.  If only it were true.

Comment: It seems to be saying that efficiency would be near perfect if we greatly oversized our heat pumps.  Use a lot of fluid moving very slowly at  low delta T but keeping Q high with volume.  Do we believe it is that easy?